# codeigniter javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

Did Codigniter have inbuilt javascript lib?
else what javascript framework best for Codigniter

Comment: Yes try Jquery its good to use with codeIgniter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- CodeIgniter 1.7.2 contains 0 .js files
- I would recommend jQuery for general browser Javascript usage.

Comment: thanks recommendation. do you know any good tutorial to hoe to intergrate jQuery and codeigniter

Comment: All you'd need to do is download the core jQuery file and reference it.

Answer (score 2):

Hope these tutorials may help.

http://geekhut.org/2009/06/how-to-codeigniter-jquery-json/

http://www.mrforbes.com/thoughts/2009/01/28/a-quick-code-igniter-and-jquery-ajax-tutorial/

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/79844/

Try google and codeigniter forums for the rest...